# Port forwarding on linux local loop to connect two android emulators

Tags: android, linux, sockets, emulation, portforwarding

I am trying to communicate between two android emulators for communication , thus I am trying to forward port X to port Y on 127.0.0.1 where port X is the port I am transmitting too and Y is the one I am receiving  . Is this possible and if so how do I forward the local ports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The socat tool is useful for this:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:Y TCP:localhost:X
```

(assuming you're in Linux)

Comment: This is by far the simplest and most straightforward answer I've come across in hours.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Googling revealed [portfwd](http://portfwd.sourceforge.net/). Although it is quite ancient, it seems to do what you describe. Other results suggest that iptables may be able to do what you want as well, but there were no succinct guides that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it's easier to use emulator port redirections, either via the [AVD console](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#redirections) or the [`adb` command](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#forwardports).